# NS_ERROR_FAILURE for path.getTotalLength

Tags: javascript, svg, path

can you help me?

I make a loop on several  "path"  elements :

```
$.each($('path'), function(i, path){

var length = path.getTotalLength();

})
```

When the path is null (space character) I have this error on mozilla firefox :

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:
var length = path.getTotalLength();
```

I want to add a condition like this :

```
 $.each($('path'), function(i, path){

    if (path) {
    var length = path.getTotalLength();
    }

    })
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: By replacing d = "" by = d "M0, 0" it works

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this recently in [bug 1024860](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024860). The fix will appear in Firefox 31. In the meantime you could wrap the call to check whether a path exists using `element.hasAttribute()` and then return 0.